# Passing styling options using JSS/Material-UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've written a small wrapper component for the `Paper` Material-UI Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import {withStyles} from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    ...theme.mixins.gutters(),
    paddingTop: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
    paddingBottom: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
  },
});

const PaddedPaper = (props) => {
  const {classes, children} = props;

  return (
    <Paper className={classes.root}>
      {children}
    </Paper>
  );
};

export default withStyles(styles)(PaddedPaper);
```

Which, as you may have guessed, is used like this:

```
<PaddedPaper>
  <p>Some content.</p>
</PaddedPaper>
```

With JSS, is it possible to pass padding into `PaddedPaper` as a prop?

```
<PaddedPaper padding={20}>
  <p>Some content.</p>
</PaddedPaper>
```

Since `styles` is defined outside of the `PaddedPaper` class, and doesn't have access to `props`, how can I pull this off? Or am I thinking about this entire process incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using `withStyles`, you have access to the theme, but not props.

this is still an ongoing issue : https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/7633

easiest way to use props in your styles is using inline styles (for now)

like this:

```
function PaperSheet(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <PaddedPaper {...props} size={10}>
        <Typography variant="headline" component="h3">
          This is a sheet of paper.
        </Typography>
        <Typography component="p">
          Paper can be used to build surface or other elements for your
          application.
        </Typography>
      </PaddedPaper>
    </div>
  );
}

const PaddedPaper = props => {
  const { children, size } = props;
  console.log(size);
  return <Paper style={{ padding: size }}>{children}</Paper>;
};
```

here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/yl4671wxz